# Why do I get the wrong id somewhere, somehow?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

okay so, this is my source code.

```
var newRealID = <? print($_SESSION["mySteamID"]) ?>;
alert("MY ID = " + <? print($_SESSION["mySteamID"]) ?>);
```

and when I inspect the site or view the source code I get the following code

`var newRealID = 76561198061310076;
alert(76561198061310076);`

Which is the correct output, however, the alert box I get visually in my chrome is:

`MY ID = 76561198061310080`

I have absolutely no idea and i've been stuck here for ages..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is because the value you're using is beyond the `MAX_SAFE_INTEGER` that JS allows:

```js
console.log(76561198061310076);
console.log(Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER)
```

Due to this you number is coerced to a floating point and back again. This in turn introduces rounding errors, which accounts for the discrepancy you see in the result.

Assuming you don't need to use mathematical operations on the value, you could convert it to a string in your output:

```
var newRealID = '<? print($_SESSION["mySteamID"]) ?>';
```

Answer (score 1):

Javascript cannot handle numbers that large, so you could pass it as a string instead like this

```
var newRealID = '<? print($_SESSION["mySteamID"]) ?>';
alert("MY ID = " + newRealID);
```

Comment: But I think @RoryMcCrossan answer probably deserves to be the accepted answer as I see he has now added the same work-around of passing the number as a string as well.

Comment: yes I just saw that, first time using this website. I can allow an answer in 2 minutes :)